# Transfer data from Controller to Jsp addAttribute method in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, addattribute

I create Spring MVC project like this.
This is Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String doHello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC");
        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

And this is content of file "helloworld.jsp".

```
<body> <h1>${message }</h1> </body> // I don't know why I can't post full code
```

When i run URL "http://localhost:8080/HelloSpringMVC/hello", the result should be `Hello Spring MVC` but I got `${message }`, what's going on?

Comment: make sure you have this tag in your page :
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

Comment: @tcharaf I add this "<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>" but result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have javax expression language dependency in your project.

Comment: are you using any build tool like maven,ant or gradle?If yes, you can add  javax el dependency through your build config file.Otherwise you can download el jars from internet and put them in `web-inf/lib` directory

Answer (score 0):

add  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> to jsp file.

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello ${message }
</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView doHello() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("helloworld");  
        model.addObject("message", "Hello Spring MVC");
        return model;
    }
}
```